# Access Azure Virtual Machine File Structure from outside the VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have Windows Server 2016 Azure Virtual Machines using managed disks.

I am trying to create an Azure Data Factory pipeline that will let me copy certain files from a folder on the hard drives of those VMs, to our Azure SQL Server.  I was quite surprised to see no ADF connectors available for Azure VMs; then I checked Logic Apps - same issue, no available connectors for connecting to Azure VM's there either.

Then I did some Googling to find out how, in general, you can access an Azure VM file structure from outside (without using Remote Desktop) and was even more surprised to see that there isn't any info out there about this (not even that it *can't* be done).

Is it possible for me to access the file system of my Windows Server 2016 Azure VM without using Remote Desktop? The VM's are running Managed Disks if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can either ssh your_vm_ip and then use rsync command to download or upload files.

rsync -au --progress your_user_name@ip.ip.ip.ip:/remote_dir/remote_dir/ /local_dir/local_dir/

Otherwise you can install Dropbox in the VM and your local computer, transfering small files in the shared Dropbox folder is very fast..

Comment: Reading up on Rsync, it says it's a Linux-only utility.  Am I missing something there?

Comment: Sorry that I must have imagined you are transferring files between Linux/Mac machines.. There are rsync equivalents in Windows https://superuser.com/questions/69514/windows-alternative-to-rsync

Comment: Yes I actually have Azure Storage Explorer, but this only lets me browse our Storage Accounts.  Are Managed VM disks accessible in Storage Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some instruction slides on the Azure storage system and their Storage Explorer App.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I definitely have a lot of experience with our Storage Accounts, but I don't think the data from the virtual hard disks of our Azure VM's are accessible in there.  Let me know if I'm not correct in that assumption.

Comment: While this is helpful info and I appreciate the screenshots, you can't access managed disks in the storage accounts.